# Collections manipulation, need help optimizing this code from a report generator

Tags: c#, linq, optimization

I'm creating a report generating tool that use custom data type of different sources from our system. The user can create a report schema and depending on what asked, the data get associated based different index keys, time, time ranges, etc. The project is NOT doing queries in a relational database, it's pure C# code in collections from RAM.

I'm having a huge performance issue and I'm looking at my code since a few days and struggle with trying to optimize it.

I stripped down the code to the minimum for a short example of what the profiler point as the problematic algorithm, but the real version is a bit more complex with more conditions and working with dates.

In short, this function return a subset of "values" satisfying the conditions depending on the keys of the values that were selected from the "index rows".

```
private List<LoadedDataSource> GetAssociatedValues(IReadOnlyCollection<List<LoadedDataSource>> indexRows, List<LoadedDataSource> values)
{
    var checkContainers = ((ValueColumn.LinkKeys & ReportLinkKeys.ContainerId) > 0 &&
                           values.Any(t => t.ContainerId.HasValue));

    var checkEnterpriseId = ((ValueColumn.LinkKeys & ReportLinkKeys.EnterpriseId) > 0 &&
                             values.Any(t => t.EnterpriseId.HasValue));

    var ret = new List<LoadedDataSource>();
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        var valid = true;

        foreach (var index in indexRows)
        {
            // ContainerId
            var indexConservedSource = index.AsEnumerable();
            if (checkContainers && index.CheckContainer && value.ContainerId.HasValue)
            {
                indexConservedSource = indexConservedSource.Where(t => t.ContainerId.HasValue && t.ContainerId.Value == value.ContainerId.Value);
                if (!indexConservedSource.Any())
                {
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //EnterpriseId
            if (checkEnterpriseId && index.CheckEnterpriseId && value.EnterpriseId.HasValue)
            {
                indexConservedSource = indexConservedSource.Where(t => t.EnterpriseId.HasValue && t.EnterpriseId.Value == value.EnterpriseId.Value);
                if (!indexConservedSource.Any())
                {
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (valid)
            ret.Add(value);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

This works for small samples, but as soon as I have thousands of values, and 2-3 index rows with a few dozens values too, it can take hours to generate.

As you can see, I try to break as soon as a index condition fail and pass to the next value.

I could probably do everything in a single "values.Where(####).ToList()", but that condition get complex fast.

I tried generating a IQueryable around indexConservedSource but it was even worse. I tried using a Parallel.ForEach with a ConcurrentBag for "ret", and it was also slower.

What else can be done?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing, in principle, is calculating intersection of two sequences. You use two nested loops and that is slow as the time is O(m*n). You have two other options:

1. sort both sequences and merge them
2. convert one sequence into hash table and test the second against it

The second approach seems better for this scenario. Just convert those index lists into HashSet and test values against it. I added some code for inspiration:

```
private List<LoadedDataSource> GetAssociatedValues(IReadOnlyCollection<List<LoadedDataSource>> indexRows, List<LoadedDataSource> values)
{
    var ret = values;

    if ((ValueColumn.LinkKeys & ReportLinkKeys.ContainerId) > 0 &&
        ret.Any(t => t.ContainerId.HasValue))
    {
        var indexes = indexRows
            .Where(i => i.CheckContainer)
            .Select(i => new HashSet<int>(i
                .Where(h => h.ContainerId.HasValue)
                .Select(h => h.ContainerId.Value)))
            .ToList();

        ret = ret.Where(v => v.ContainerId == null 
                        || indexes.All(i => i.Contains(v.ContainerId)))
                 .ToList();
    }

    if ((ValueColumn.LinkKeys & ReportLinkKeys.EnterpriseId) > 0 &&
        ret.Any(t => t.EnterpriseId.HasValue))
    {
        var indexes = indexRows
            .Where(i => i.CheckEnterpriseId)
            .Select(i => new HashSet<int>(i
                .Where(h => h.EnterpriseId.HasValue)
                .Select(h => h.EnterpriseId.Value)))
            .ToList();

        ret = ret.Where(v => v.EnterpriseId == null 
                        || indexes.All(i => i.Contains(v.EnterpriseId)))
                 .ToList();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Unfortunately, unless I misunderstand your solution, I think it's not that simple. I don't have two sequences, I have a sequence (values) and a sequence of sequences (index). In order for a value to be accepted, it needs to pass all conditions on at least one element in each indexes. I also don't see how I can use an HashSet, because I don't have a single key to index on, but multiple ones which are all optional (containerId, enterpriseId, dateStart, dateEnd, etc).

Comment: After thinking about HashSet a bit more, I understand what you mean. I guess I could reorganize my data differently. Instead of having a list of "LoadedDataSource" class containing the different nullable keys and the value, I could have an HashSet of each int keys, and a sorted list for date keys. I just don't know where I would put the value. It would also be problematic for keeping the order since my list is currently presorted based on a different condition, I would need to keep another index to re-sort them afterward.. still not perfectly clear.

Comment: This seems perfect. My brain was too focused at trying to pre-calculate the hashes for all those lists beforehand while keeping the values and order, I never thought about hashing them at this point where the values of the indexes aren't required for the association. Awesome. Quick remark, wouldn't it be more efficient to call ToList() only once at the return?

Comment: @Dunge May be, but on the other hand it would need values.Any(...) instead of ret.Any(...) to avoid multiple enumeration, which would decrease the efficiency. And from memory perspective it is better not to need to use all those hash arrays at the same time.

Comment: The solution does answer my question with the hashset to fix performance. Unfortunately looking back at it my original code was wrong and did not satisfy my requirement. In order for a value to be accepted, it needs to satisfy ALL conditions on at least one element in each indexes. As of now, it check for at least one element that satisfy each conditions in each indexes independently. A value that have a containerId match and an enterpriseId match in another element of the same index would pass where it shouldn't. I need to combine my keys, and this way separate hashset isn't applicable.

Comment: Scratch that, my original code was correct. It was "conserving" the entries in the index row that pass, and filter on them. Separating them in multiples hashset like you did lost the combination. I had to unmark your answer as the solution because it returned a different result.

Comment: I ran some tests on dummy data and resuts of my code were the same as results of the code in Your question. The problem seems to be outside of information on this page. But I tried to show ways on abstract level in the first case anyway, the code was just a bonus. If you really want someone to code it for you, you need to make a complete example with sample data and desired result in the first place.